# Samsung Galaxy S21 : Lineage Recovery: Failed to mount dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/cache

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, lineageos, android-14

[tree](https://github.com/LucasBlackLu/android_device_samsung_sm8350-common)
[kernel](https://github.com/LucasBlackLu/android_kernel_samsung_sm8350)
[CLO fstab.qcom](https://git.codelinaro.org/clo/la/platform/vendor/qcom/lahaina/-/blob/LA.UM.9.14.r1-24100-LAHAINA.QSSI14.0/default/fstab_non_AB.qcom?ref_type=tags)
[samsung ode fstab flag](https://github.com/LucasBlackLu/android_device_samsung_sm8350-common/blob/35a58b12f148954f6259d37ff232911aeebf2f78/init/fstab.default#L67)

```
ERROR: recovery:inotify_add_watch failed: No such file or directly
ERROR: recovery: [libfs_mgr] skipping mounting ' /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/cache '
ERROR: recovery: [libfs_mgr] Failed to open '/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/cache ' No such file or directory
ERROR: recovery: [libfs_mgr] Failed to open /cache ' No such file or directory
ERROR: recovery: [libfs_mgr] Failed to mount for path [/cache/recovery/last_locale]
ERROR: recovery: [libfs_mgr] Failed to mount /cache/recovery/last_locale
ERROR: recovery: [libfs_mgr] Failed to clear BCB message: failed to open dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/misc: No such file or directory
```

I met this error while building LineageOS for my Samsung Snapdragon S21 (t2q). That's all the error in recovery.

Someone told me it's fstab fault, so I tried to remove this Samsung ode flag in fstab, and even tried to use clo's fstab.qcom, also wiped factory reset. It didn't work for me according to somebody's help.

Comment: Hi! Did you ever found a solution? I have the same issue on a Redmi 8 currently.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find out the solution too, maybe you could try to build los 20 (a13),if you work plz tell me when you are free